# How do I get my images to display horizontally and all have overlays?

Tags: html, css

This is what I have tried so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="Game%20Page.htm" title="Game Page">

  <img src="Images/green-circle-hi.png" alt="Green" class="image 1" style="width: 400px": height="400px"></a>
  <div class="overlay">
  </div>

  <img src="Images/amber-clipart-face-15.png" alt="Amber" class="image 2" style="width: 400px": height="400px">
  <div class="AmberOverlay">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.container {
   position: relative;
   width: 28%;
}

.overlay {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: .5s ease;
   background-image: url(Images/Green%20circle%20Overlay.jpg);
   background-size: cover;
   border-radius: 50%;
}
.container:hover .overlay {
   opacity: 1;
}

.container {
   position:absolute;
   width: 28%;
}

.AmberOverlay {
   position:absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: .5s ease;
   background-image: url(Images/Green%20circle%20Overlay.jpg);
   background-size: cover;
   border-radius: 50%;
}
.Amber:hover .AmberOverlay {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

I want to get the images to be on the same horizontal line and have a seperate overlay for all of them, how do I changed or add to this code to make that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap each of the image-overlay pairs in a div and have that div be `position: relative`, the overlay then is `position: absolute` and can be stretched to the parents size set by the image.

```
<div class="box">
  <img src="Images/green-circle-hi.png" alt="Green" class="image 1" style="width: 400px": height="400px"></a>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <img src="Images/amber-clipart-face-15.png" alt="Amber" class="image 2" style="width: 400px": height="400px">
  <div class="AmberOverlay"></div>
</div>
```

in your css:

```
.box {
  postion: realtive;
}

.overlay, .AmberOverlay { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

I created an example in jsfiddle so you can see the result: https://jsfiddle.net/hpkc04kn/.

Comment: YES! this has worked thank you. How would I now get more of a gap between the two images?

Comment: To get a gap simply add `margin` to your margin to the surrounding boxes. i.e: `.box { margin: 10px;}` Please accept the answer if it helped you (and +1 it)

Comment: awesome, one more thing, how would I get the overlay to be a link to another page?

Comment: make it an anchor tag with an href. instead of `<div class="AmberOverlay"></div>` use `<a class="AmberOverlay" href="google.com">`

Comment: you're a life saver nayish